# JavaScript array show10 images then next 10

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help with some logic. I have a JSon feed with 600 images. I want to show the first 10 pictures. When the user gets to the tenth picture, if there are more pictures in the array show the next 10 images.   I already tweaked json to give me just 10 images but I am not sure how to get the next 10 items in the array.  I knowthis hassomething to do with a counter but its all not connecting for me.  Any suggestions, pseudeo code,links or code is apprecaited.

Thank you

Comment: We will need more information. Specifically, how do you retrieve the JSON feed? All 600 images at a time, or a 'n' number of images at a time? Do you have access to the server which provides this feed? And what do you mean by 'get to'? Do you mean scroll to, or navigate to (using Next/Forward buttons)?

Comment: what is structure of json feed ?

Comment: how did you "tweak json"? JSON is a transport format, it does not have logic. there can be no "tweaking" done to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just pseudeo in java script. Just analyse the loop.

Just start collecting images from Json feed into array container. As you get 10 images, display them with function and clean the container. Keep on doing till all images are over.
Show the last few images which are less than ten by calling function again.

I couldn't give exact code becuase, json feed structure is now known.

```
var jsonFeed={...}; 
var counter=0;
var setOfTenImages=[];
for(i=0;i<jsonFeed.length;i++){
   if(counter==10){
     showTenImages(setOfTenImages);  // call function to display Ten Images
     setOfTenImages=[];              // clean all container of Ten images which are displayed.   
   }
   setOfTenImages[counter++]=jsonFeed[i].image;
}
  showTenImages(setOfTenImages); // Last remaining few images which are less than ten.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  There is only one piece of code I dont understand.  What does showTenImages(setOfTenImages);  mean?  I know its calling my array, but why am I using the same name to hold my array?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches I can think of to load the content.

1. Create DOM with all the photos and show only first 10. Hide the rest. Show next 10 once you hit the visible 10th item.
2. Keep the reference to JSON object Render only first 10. On hitting the 10th hide current 10 n show next 10.

You haven't mentioned if you want to scroll horizontally or vertically.
Create 2 divs with parent having width fixed and child div containing a target images with huge width

You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ch4nd4n/LS7VV/4/ this may not be exactly what you want but you can get the idea.

HTML structure

```
<div style="width:500px;overflow:hidden;height:255px;position:relative">
    <div id="images" style="width:40000px;position:absolute;"></div>
</div>​
```

JavaScript part that you need to fire onload or post body load.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=60474555@N00&lang=en-us&jsoncallback=?", {
    format: "json"
}, function(data) {
    var str = "";
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        str += ("<img src='" + item.media.m + "'/>");
    });
    $("#images").append(str);
    $("#images").find("img").click(function() {
        // Add check to animate only if clicked image is not the center of parent div
        $('#images').animate({
            left: '-=200'
        }, 500);

    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  This is useful.  Its good to have another way to think about implementing my code.